# How to refuse delivering emails that are not signed by trusted PGP keys?

Tags: email, pgp

I'm fed up by spam and would like to have an email address that will only deliver mails signed by users I declared trusted. Some kind of purgatory for mails the signatures of which are trustworthy by a Web of Trust connection would of course also be a nice feature. Is there a either provider that offers this service, or at least a (preferably FOSS) mail server setup for self-hosting?

Comment: Unless you often get e-mails from people you don't know yet and are in your WoT, setting up a white-list on e-mail address will be easier. That being said, most OSS MTA and MDA do allow scripting, so in theory you should be able to hook it up to gpg.

Comment: @HubertKario Good point, although the WoT is probably the closest thing to some intelligent friends-of-friends / colleagues-of-colleagues etc. whitelist... (Now please don't tell me I should use Facebook for that)

Comment: but then you'd have to have friends that actually use gpg and have cross-signed their public keys. From my experience, it's not really common in IT/security circles, let alone geeks or general population. You may have different friends/colleagues though...

Comment: @HubertKario nah, I'm rather optimistic :-7 This functionality might however be very convincing for non-geeks to use GPG...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler No, it won´t. Will convice them of not writing any email to you though.

Comment: @droope that _may_ be a good thing after all m-/

Comment: @TobiasKienzler agreed!

Comment: Hi Tobias, shopping / recommendation questions are not really a good fit for SE. Do you want to ask something more like, how could a good solution solve this?

Comment: @AviD That's true. Jeff's edit gave me some directions, I hope it's less shopping-y now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Unix MTA can pipe mail to a script. Run signature checks on the server and if the script returns true, pass the mail on. See your favorite MTA's documentation for an explanation of how. This is the same kind of setup used to create listserves.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's probably the more correct question to ask. (Accepted answer, though an actual example configuration with scripts would of course steal the checkmark :-P )

Answer (score 0):

We are currently in development of this functionality as a Cloud Application that will run in your private cloud on the Jumpto.com Internet Security platform. Secure Mail will eradicate spam by making your email address unresolvable on the normal Internet by unauthorized users. More information on the product will be released upon roll out in the next few weeks.

Comment: Sounds interesting, please update your answer and drop a comment when that happens. Also, welcome to security.SE! But also be aware of the faq entry on promotion: http://security.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion